ros1_bridge build error in windows
I'm trying to build ros1_bridge package in windows 11
My step is
1.Create folder name ros1_bridge_ws/src
2.Download from https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge foxy branch and extract it under src
3.run x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2019 as Admin
4.source ros noetic (c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\setup.bat)
5.source ros foxy (c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\setup.bat)
6.colcon build --executor sequential --symlink-install --packages-select ros1_bridge --cmake-force-configure
I get colcon build fail exit code 1
This is my stdout_stderr.log

  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/ros1_bridge_ws2/src/ros1_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
  geometry_msgs__msg__AccelWithCovariance__factories.cpp
  geometry_msgs__msg__PoseWithCovariance__factories.cpp
  geometry_msgs__msg__TwistWithCovariance__factories.cpp
  sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp
  sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp
  sensor_msgs__msg__MagneticField__factories.cpp
  sensor_msgs__msg__NavSatFix__factories.cpp
  shape_msgs__msg__MeshTriangle__factories.cpp
  shape_msgs__msg__Plane__factories.cpp
  unique_identifier_msgs__msg__UUID__factories.cpp
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\boost/bind.hpp(41): message : The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__Plane__factories.cpp(61,28): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__Plane__factories.cpp(61,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__Plane__factories.cpp(61,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__Plane__factories.cpp(84,28): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__Plane__factories.cpp(84,32): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__Plane__factories.cpp(84,32): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__PoseWithCovariance__factories.cpp(69,34): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__PoseWithCovariance__factories.cpp(69,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__PoseWithCovariance__factories.cpp(69,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__PoseWithCovariance__factories.cpp(100,34): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__PoseWithCovariance__factories.cpp(100,38): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__PoseWithCovariance__factories.cpp(100,38): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\unique_identifier_msgs__msg__UUID__factories.cpp(61,28): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\unique_identifier_msgs__msg__UUID__factories.cpp(61,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\unique_identifier_msgs__msg__UUID__factories.cpp(61,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\unique_identifier_msgs__msg__UUID__factories.cpp(84,28): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\unique_identifier_msgs__msg__UUID__factories.cpp(84,32): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\unique_identifier_msgs__msg__UUID__factories.cpp(84,32): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__AccelWithCovariance__factories.cpp(69,34): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__AccelWithCovariance__factories.cpp(69,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__AccelWithCovariance__factories.cpp(69,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__AccelWithCovariance__factories.cpp(100,34): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__AccelWithCovariance__factories.cpp(100,38): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__AccelWithCovariance__factories.cpp(100,38): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__TwistWithCovariance__factories.cpp(69,34): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__TwistWithCovariance__factories.cpp(69,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__TwistWithCovariance__factories.cpp(69,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__TwistWithCovariance__factories.cpp(100,34): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__TwistWithCovariance__factories.cpp(100,38): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\geometry_msgs__msg__TwistWithCovariance__factories.cpp(100,38): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(91,25): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(91,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(91,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(103,25): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(103,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(103,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(115,25): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(115,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(115,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(184,25): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(184,29): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(184,29): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(196,25): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(196,29): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(196,29): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(208,25): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(208,29): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__CameraInfo__factories.cpp(208,29): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__MeshTriangle__factories.cpp(61,38): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__MeshTriangle__factories.cpp(61,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__MeshTriangle__factories.cpp(61,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__MeshTriangle__factories.cpp(84,38): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__MeshTriangle__factories.cpp(84,42): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\shape_msgs__msg__MeshTriangle__factories.cpp(84,42): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__NavSatFix__factories.cpp(89,43): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__NavSatFix__factories.cpp(89,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__NavSatFix__factories.cpp(89,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__NavSatFix__factories.cpp(144,43): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__NavSatFix__factories.cpp(144,47): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__NavSatFix__factories.cpp(144,47): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__MagneticField__factories.cpp(77,49): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__MagneticField__factories.cpp(77,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__MagneticField__factories.cpp(77,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__MagneticField__factories.cpp(116,49): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__MagneticField__factories.cpp(116,53): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__MagneticField__factories.cpp(116,53): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(77,46): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(77,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(77,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(97,51): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(97,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(97,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(117,54): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(117,6): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(117,6): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(156,46): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(156,50): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(156,50): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(176,51): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(176,55): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(176,55): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(196,54): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(196,58): message : failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\generated\sensor_msgs__msg__Imu__factories.cpp(196,58): message : see usage of 'ros2_msg' [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\ros1_bridge.vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule C:/ros1_bridge_ws2/src/ros1_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
simple_bridge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool ros::console::g_initialized" (?g_initialized@console@ros@@3_NA) referenced in function "public: virtual class boost::shared_ptr<void const > __cdecl ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<class ros::MessageEvent<struct std_msgs::String_<class std::allocator<void> > const > const &,void>::deserialize(struct ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParams const &)" (?deserialize@?$SubscriptionCallbackHelperT@AEBV?$MessageEvent@$$CBU?$String_@V?$allocator@X@std@@@std_msgs@@@ros@@X@ros@@UEAA?AV?$shared_ptr@$$CBX@boost@@AEBUSubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParams@2@@Z) [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\simple_bridge.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\Release\simple_bridge.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\simple_bridge.vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule C:/ros1_bridge_ws2/src/ros1_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
simple_bridge_1_to_2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool ros::console::g_initialized" (?g_initialized@console@ros@@3_NA) referenced in function "public: virtual class boost::shared_ptr<void const > __cdecl ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<class boost::shared_ptr<struct std_msgs::String_<class std::allocator<void> > const > const &,void>::deserialize(struct ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParams const &)" (?deserialize@?$SubscriptionCallbackHelperT@AEBV?$shared_ptr@$$CBU?$String_@V?$allocator@X@std@@@std_msgs@@@boost@@X@ros@@UEAA?AV?$shared_ptr@$$CBX@boost@@AEBUSubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParams@2@@Z) [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\simple_bridge_1_to_2.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\Release\simple_bridge_1_to_2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\simple_bridge_1_to_2.vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule C:/ros1_bridge_ws2/src/ros1_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
  simple_bridge_2_to_1.vcxproj -> C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\Release\simple_bridge_2_to_1.exe
  Building Custom Rule C:/ros1_bridge_ws2/src/ros1_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
test_ros1_client.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool ros::console::g_initialized" (?g_initialized@console@ros@@3_NA) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl ros::ServiceClient::deserializeFailed(class std::exception const &)" (?deserializeFailed@ServiceClient@ros@@AEAAXAEBVexception@std@@@Z) [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\test_ros1_client.vcxproj]
C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\Release\test_ros1_client.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\test_ros1_client.vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule C:/ros1_bridge_ws2/src/ros1_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
  test_ros1_server.vcxproj -> C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\Release\test_ros1_server.exe
  Building Custom Rule C:/ros1_bridge_ws2/src/ros1_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
  test_ros2_client_cpp.vcxproj -> C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\Release\test_ros2_client_cpp.exe
  Building Custom Rule C:/ros1_bridge_ws2/src/ros1_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
  test_ros2_server_cpp.vcxproj -> C:\ros1_bridge_ws2\build\ros1_bridge\Release\test_ros2_server_cpp.exe


I'm using Windows 11, Ros noetic and Foxy build with chocolatey by this link
Please help
